# Странный синтаксис в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(2 in lst == True)
```

Почему вывод = False???

Comment: потому что  `TRUE`

Comment: Минус за заголовок, совершенно не относящийся к предмету вопроса.